# Change button text and do corresponding onClick function in android studio

Tags: java, android

I am trying to change an image dynamically on first button press and once the image is changed ,the button text should change and if we press on the button this time,it must open a new activity. But as of now the below code doesn't seem to run and crashes on clicking the button ,the first time.

```
   @Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    final int status = (Integer) v.getTag();
    if (status == 1) {
       change(v);
       btn2.setText(R.string.next);
        v.setTag(0); 
        next(v);
    } else
        {
        btn2.setText(R.string.command);
        v.setTag(1); 
    }
  }


 public void change(View v) {
   btn2.setTag(1);
   btn2.setText(R.string.command);
   ImageView doggy = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
   doggy.setImageResource(R.drawable.dog_sit);
 }

public void next(View v){
    v.setTag(0);
       Intent i = new Intent(this, NumberShapes.class);
       startActivity(i);

   }
```

The error pointed out by logcat is as follows:-

```
07-03 21:44:19.944 31179-31179/com.example.angelinekingsteena.myapplication 
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.angelinekingsteena.myapplication, PID: 31179
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int 
java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference
    at 
com.example.angelinekingsteena.myapplication.Doggie.onClick(Doggie.java:37)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5207)
```

according to logcat the error lies in the below line

```
 final int status = (Integer) v.getTag();
```

Comment: Post your logs of what exception's you are getting.

Comment: Hey @FLORA your code is pretty confusing, you are setting the _btn2_'s text to `command` and `next` at the same time. And call the methods _change_ and _next_ at the same time too. So, please clarify those things and put a screenshot, if you could.

Comment: don't you read the answers?

Comment: @ThawinduAngeshTuto I have presumed my code would change the image dynamically by the method call change() and then change the text to next and then if clicked again would start a new activity by the method call next(). I hope it's right.

Comment: Alright, then my answer seems about right. Do you need more explanation for my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do this with a Switch-Case Statement on your onClick method, use a flag to start, so, if you press the button first time, change the image, the text and change the flag value, if you press it once again, with the new flag value, will go to the other case and you can open the activity from there.

Comment: Thank for your suggestion ,I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

Change 
`final int status = (Integer) v.getTag();` 
to: 
`final String status = v.getTag().toString;` 
and use and compare the tags as strings. 
Also I hope you have in xml set the initial tag to 1.

Comment: I changed the code as you pointed out but didn't know how to set the initial tag to 1 in xml,so got the same error in the changed line too. Could you please enunciate how to do that in xml?

Comment: tags are not `int`. This is why your app crashed

Comment: change all your `setTag(0)` and `setTag(1)` to `setTag("0")` and `setTag("1")` and in your activity's oncreate write: `btn2.setTag("1")`. Then change your if to `if (status == "1")`

Comment: oh !! Alright will do the necessary changes.Thanks for taking a keen look at it and helping,appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this, getting and setting the `Button`'s *tag* didn't seem necessary for me, I I thought just creating a variable on the *Global scope* would do the same job, but for less hassle.

```
private static int status = 0;

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (status) {
        case 0:
            change(v);
            btn2.setText(R.string.next);
            status = 1;
            break;  
        case 1:
            next(v)
            break;     
    } }
```

**Keep in mind:** Next time when asking a question, try to explain the things a little more. Your code didn't really match up with what you were trying to do in the first place, *at all*.

> **EDIT:** I added this line of code on the *1st* `case` of the `switch`statement
>
> ```
> btn2.setText(R.string.next);
> ```

**Good luck, *hope this answer helped!***

Comment: Thanks a lot for your guidance through this. The code you provided did exactly what I had in mind. But the button text is not changing to next after the first click.Could you please tell me how to go about it .

Comment: I edited the code but that line of code is causing an error and crashing the app.But with that line commented out,the rest of the code works seamlessly.

Comment: @FLORA Try changing that new line I told you to add to `(Button) (v.setText(R.string.next));`

Comment: This is the error:-       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setText(int)' on a null object reference.     And I tried replacing the      btn2.setText(R.string.next)      with      (Button)(v.setText(R.string.next));    but got the compilation error as "cannot resolve error setText (int) .

Comment: I think it was a small error on parenthesis, try changing it to, `(Button) v.setText(R.string.next);`

Comment: It shows cannot resolve method setText(int)   again even after changing the parenthesis.

Comment: Delete that line of code and add this: `Button button = findViewById(R.id.{your button id});`
`button.setText(R.string.next);`

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked like magic . Thanks for your time and patience. :D

Comment: Awesome! Glad to help to you out!